# How to change the navigation in dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015, crm-sitemap

I tried creating a solution and I clicked on "`Add existing item`" and selected the "`Sitemap`".
But when I click on the sitemap to edit it nothing happens.

How can I customize the top level tile navigation in CRM ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For easier editing of sitemap you will have to use some tool like XrmToolbox.

Comment: @vignesh Not sure what you mean by editing it along with the solution.  Once you use the sitemap editor in the xrmtoolbox, then you can re-export the sitemap with your solution.

Comment: @vignesh After you have updated sitemap in an `dev env`, you add it to the solution and import in other org like `test env`.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit `SiteMap` in CRM either manually or using some tool.

On the url below microsoft has mentioned:

`Using a sitemap editor can facilitate editing the sitemap.
 A popular one is included in the Toolbox for Dynamics CRM 2011/2013 released by Microsoft CRM MVP Tanguy Touzard`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309424.aspx#BKMK_SiteMapEditors

I use `SiteMap Editor for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011`. It is super easy to use.
http://mscrmtools.blogspot.com/2011/06/new-tool-sitemap-editor-for-microsoft.html

Answer (score 0):

In the [XrmToolBox](http://www.xrmtoolbox.com/), open the SiteMap editor

[image: SiteMap editor]

Connect to an organisation if not already done:

[image: Connect to an organisation]

In the dialogue, click on the **New Connection**

[image: New Connection]

Provide credentials. After auth, provide it a name.

In the SiteMap editor, click **Load SiteMap** and update the nodes as needed

[image: update the SiteMap nodes]

Click **Update SiteMap**