# Editing the site map manually in Dynamics CRM

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dynamics-crm

I'm getting the below error

[image]

when [importing an updated solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309424.aspx#Anchor_2). The message says nothing but a generic error.

Is there any known issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fails because there probably is an invalid site map node. 
Please use [XrmToolBox](https://github.com/MscrmTools/XrmToolBox) site map editor, that way you don't have to worry about invalid nodes and cut copy paste errors which usually occur during manual edit.

Comment: @dynamicallyCRM - Tried doing this in Firefox which was able to tell the exact issue (the one which you said - **Invalid XML**). Maybe CRM is not good in showing errors on Chrome, but on Firefox

Comment: @dynamicallyCRM - Tried doing this in Firefox which was able to tell the exact issue (the one which you said - `Invalid XML`). Maybe CRM is not good in showing errors on Chrome, but on Firefox. Anyways, I have kept the [SiteMap editor steps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40356543/2404470) for my future reference